# MySQL hung up on "activating (start-post)" status after relocating datadir

Tags: mysql

The conundrum: After changing where MySQL stores its data (to a different hard drive), and updating the apparmor permissions, starting the MySQL service seems to put it in this weird "activating" state and the logs won't give me any information as to why it's failing.

Any ideas on how I can get MySQL started back up? ([Pastebin of "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe"](https://pastebin.com/YscGkQQK)

**STEPS TAKEN**

1. Stopped the service

`sudo service mysql stop`

2. Relocated the MySQL file:

`sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /mnt/HDDB/database/mysql`

3. Changed the location of the data dir in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to:

`datadir=/mnt/HDDB/database/mysql`

4. Add the AppArmor alias in `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`

`alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /mnt/HDDB/database/mysql/,`

5. Added a couple of lines to `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`

`/mnt/HDDB/database/mysql/ r,`
`/mnt/HDDB/database/mysql/** rwk,`

and to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

`/proc/** r,`

`/sys/devices/system/node/ r,`

`/sys/devices/system/node/** r,`

...to prevent anymore possible AppArmor denial errors. I'm sure it should be working after reading a plethora of StackExhange posts with similar problems but I have no clue what's causing the hangup.

MySQL does work as intended when the data dir is set to its default location, but it's not where I want it storing the data (default drive is an SSD), so any help to get it past the hangup would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Begs the question, why change from the defaults ? Does it work when apparmor is disabled ? If so then check your logs for aa denials.

Comment: I'd rather it not store database information on my SSD, especially when the data starts getting large, hence the change from default. I stopped and toredown the apparmor process and there's still a hangup when I try to start MySQL back up.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change anything in

```
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias
```

,just change

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

I changed this:

```
# Allow data dir access
#  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
#  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
/mnt/largedisk/mysql/ r,
/mnt/largedisk/mysql/** rwk,
```

works.